# How do I detect collision with spawned objects?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim i As Integer    'integer for spawning
    Dim maxball As Integer = 50 'max ball able to be created
    Dim RateX(maxball) As Integer   'rate of movement
    Dim RateY(maxball) As Integer   'rate of movement
    Dim ball(maxball) As PictureBox 'spawned ball is a picture box
    Dim rnd As New Random   'random number generator
    Dim rndLoc As Integer   'random locatino generator
    Dim Loc As Point    'location is a point on the screen
    Dim create As Integer   'integer to create new balls
    Dim score As Integer = 0    'score is 0 but can increase

    'move the ball
    Private Sub moveball()
        'For Each ball(ec) In ball
        For i As Integer = 0 To create - 1
            If ball(i).Left <= pbArena.Left Then   'bounce off left side
                RateX(i) *= -1
            End If
            If ball(i).Right >= pbArena.Right Then   'bounce off right side
                RateX(i) *= -1
            End If
            If ball(i).Top <= pbArena.Top Then    'bounce off top
                RateY(i) *= -1
            End If
            If ball(i).Bottom >= pbArena.Bottom Then  'bounce off bottom
                RateY(i) *= -1
            End If
            '====================================================================================================================================================
            ball(i).Left += RateX(i)  'moves the ball horizontally
            ball(i).Top += RateY(i) 'moves the ball vertically
            '====================================================================================================================================================
        Next
    End Sub
    'create the ball
    Private Sub createball()
        If create <= 50 Then    '50 is max amount to
            create += 1 'add 1 to create
            ball(i) = New PictureBox    'ball is a picture box
            ball(i).Size = New Size(45, 45) 'set size
            ball(i).BackColor = Color.Red   'set color
            '====================================================================================================================================================
            ball(i).Top = rnd.Next(pbArena.Height - ball(i).Height)    'sets random y
            ball(i).Left = rnd.Next(pbArena.Width - ball(i).Width)     'sets random x
            '====================================================================================================================================================
            RateX(i) = rnd.Next(-4, 4)   'random X direction/speed
            RateY(i) = rnd.Next(-4, 4)   'random Y direction/speed
            '====================================================================================================================================================
            Me.Controls.Add(ball(i))    'actually add teh ball
            ball(i).BringToFront()  'bring to front so arena isn't in front
            i += 1
        End If
    End Sub
    'commands for when you touch black box
    Private Sub pbTarget_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pbTarget.MouseEnter
        pbTarget.Top = rnd.Next(pbArena.Height - pbTarget.Height)    'sets random y
        pbTarget.Left = rnd.Next(pbArena.Width - pbTarget.Width)     'sets random x
        '====================================================================================================================================================
        'scoring system
        score = score + 1
        lblScore.Text = score
        createball()    'creates a new ball
    End Sub
    'what happens when the timer ticks
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        moveball()  'every timer tick the ball will move IF its created
        ball(i) = New PictureBox    'ball is a picture box
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is my code so far. Each time the mouse intersects with the target (which is a picture box) is moves. I am replicating this game. http://www.lewpen.com/game/ I have used an array to spawn red squares on the form. I want to be able to detect when my mouse enters them. I know how to do this with picture boxes, but these are all spawned objects called ball(i). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to know how to add an event handler to a dynamically created control.  `these are all spawned objects called ball(i)` but they are all just pictureboxes.  You can add event handlers when you create the balls (pictureboxes)

```
Private Sub createball(BallIndex As Integer)
   Dim ball As New PictureBox    'ball is a picture box
   ' give it a name so we can find it
   ' ball index is PASSED to avoid sloppy global vars
   ball.Name = "Ball" & BallIndex.ToString 
   ' etc
   Me.Controls.Add(ball)
   AddHandler ball.MouseEnter, AddressOf BallMouseEnter
```

Elsewhere, you'd add the code for the event:

```
Private Sub BallMouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    ' your code here
End Sub
```

Since the balls exist as controls in the Controls collection there is really no reason to keep a reference to them in an array.  If you name them "Ball1", "Ball2" you can make them move by referencing them by name:

```
Me.Controls(ballname)
```

Where BallName would be `"Ball" & index.ToString` and index would be the ball/picturebox to move (like the `i` variable).  **EDIT** More info:

```
Private Sub moveballS()
    Dim ball As PictureBox

    ' loop thru ballS
    For n As Integer = 0 To BallCount
        ' current ball from name
        ball = Me.Controls("Ball" & n.ToString)

        ' your code here
        If ball.Left <= pbArena.Left Then 
        ' etc
        End If

        ' you CAN just reference them in controls(),
        ' but it is wordy:
        If Controls("Ball" & n.ToString).Left <= pbArena.Left Then 
            ' etc
        End If

     Next n
End Sub
```

Another way to track them is just a List(Of String) to store the name, but that is equally unneeded if you can get them by name from Controls() as above:

```
Dim ballList As New List(Of String)

' when you create a ball:
ballList.Add(ball.Name)
```

to get a control reference:

```
For n As Integer = 0 To ballList.Count - 1
   ball = Me.Controls(ballList(n))
   ' etc
```

It can be a bad idea to create a separate reference to dynamically created controls (like an array) since that ref can prevent the object from being disposed of if/when you reset or start over and are deleting balls/pictureboxes.

Comment: While this is amazing advice, I don't understand how to replicate my code without using an array. Furthermore, when I add the event handler code, i can't "dim ball as new picture box." Your code makes sense to me but vb just won't accept it.  This works                ball(i) = New PictureBox    
Me.Controls.Add(ball(i))          but when i add ball(i)addhandler i get an error "'addhandler' is not a member of 'System.windows.forms.picturebox'."

Comment: @Canucksctr7  sorry, there was a typo in AddHandler - see edit.  I also added info on getting rid of the nasty arrays (ie using the ctrl name to get a control reference back to move the balls).

Comment: this is great and solved all my problems. You are a great guy, and if I had the reputation I'd upvote you ;) thanks again